# How do you put a text file with strings and integers into a dictionary>

Tags: dictionary

I have a text file like this:

```
red 5
orange 2
red 7
```

How would I put it into a dictionary so it says

```
{red: 12, orange: 2}
```

Comment: Are you asking about Python?

Comment: Please take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see what questions you can ask. Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.